# How to change IconButton color like a TabBar?

Tags: flutter, flutter-layout

I want to have a TabBar next to my Appbar Title instead of below it, but I am not able to add a TabBar in 'actions'. So I made a row of IconButton instead. 
The purpose of my IconButtons is to change the crossAxisCount number of a GridView. 
My goal is to change the color of the selected IconButton :

[image]

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

class TestingPage extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _TestingPageState createState() => _TestingPageState();
}

class _TestingPageState extends State<TestingPage> {
  int gridNumber = 3;
  bool isSelected = true;

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return DefaultTabController(
      length: 2,
      child: Scaffold(
        backgroundColor: Colors.white,
        appBar: AppBar(
          backgroundColor: Colors.grey,
          title: Text('Home'),
          centerTitle: true,
          actions: <Widget>[
            IconButton(
              icon: Icon(
                Icons.format_align_left,
                color: isSelected ? Colors.cyanAccent : Colors.white,
              ),
              onPressed: () {
                setState(() {
                  gridNumber = 3;
                  isSelected = true;
                });
              },
            ),
            IconButton(
              icon: Icon(
                Icons.format_align_center,
                color: isSelected ? Colors.cyanAccent : Colors.white,
              ),
              onPressed: () {
                setState(() {
                  gridNumber = 1;
                  isSelected = true;
                });
              },
            ),
            IconButton(
              icon: Icon(
                Icons.format_align_right,
                color: isSelected ? Colors.cyanAccent : Colors.white,
              ),
              onPressed: () {
                setState(() {
                  gridNumber = 5;
                  isSelected = true;
                });
              },
            ),
          ],
          bottom: TabBar(
            tabs: <Widget>[
              Tab(
                icon: Icon(
                  Icons.directions_car,
                ),
                child: Text('First Tab'),
              ),
              Tab(
                icon: Icon(
                  Icons.directions_transit,
                ),
                child: Text('Second Tab'),
              ),
            ],
          ),
        ),
        body: TabBarView(
          children: <Widget>[
            GridView.count(
              crossAxisCount: gridNumber,
              children: [
                Container(color: Colors.red, height: 150.0),
                Container(color: Colors.purple, height: 150.0),
                Container(color: Colors.green, height: 150.0),
                Container(color: Colors.orange, height: 150.0),
                Container(color: Colors.yellow, height: 150.0),
                Container(color: Colors.pink, height: 150.0),
                Container(color: Colors.cyan, height: 150.0),
                Container(color: Colors.indigo, height: 150.0),
                Container(color: Colors.blue, height: 150.0),
              ],
            ),
            Container(),
          ],
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

You will see in my code above that my color changes depending on the bool 'isSelected', but that changes the color of all the IconButtons. So I tried having different variables for each button like this:

```
bool colorOne = true;
bool colorTwo, colorThree = false;

actions: <Widget>[
            IconButton(
              icon: Icon(
                Icons.format_align_left,
                color: colorOne ? Colors.cyanAccent : Colors.white,
              ),
              onPressed: () {
                setState(() {
                  gridNumber = 3;
                  colorOne = true;
                  colorTwo = false;
                  colorThree = false;
                });
              },
            ),
            IconButton(
              icon: Icon(
                Icons.format_align_center,
                color: colorTwo ? Colors.cyanAccent : Colors.white,
              ),
              onPressed: () {
                setState(() {
                  gridNumber = 1;
                  colorOne = false;
                  colorTwo = true;
                  colorThree = false;
                });
              },
            ),
            IconButton(
              icon: Icon(
                Icons.format_align_right,
                color: colorThree ? Colors.cyanAccent : Colors.white,
              ),
              onPressed: () {
                setState(() {
                  gridNumber = 5;
                  colorOne = false;
                  colorTwo = false;
                  colorThree = true;
                });
              },
            ),
          ],
```

But when I do this I get the following Error:
"Failed assertion: boolean expression must not be null"

Comment: Write `bool colorTwo = false, colorThree = false;`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue is happening because, `colorTwo` is not initialised, it's null by default. You have to change your declaration like:

```
bool colorTwo = false, colorThree = false;
```

I would like to suggest, instead of using 3 different boolean, use an integer to keep the selected button index (Won't say that it's the best approach, but it's better than maintaining 3 different variables).

```
int selectedIndex = 0;
```

Change buttons like this:

```
<Widget>[
        IconButton(
          icon: Icon(
            Icons.format_align_left,
            color: selectedIndex == 1 ? Colors.cyanAccent : Colors.white,
          ),
          onPressed: () {
            setState(() {
              gridNumber = 3;
              selectedIndex = 1;
            });
          },
        ),
        IconButton(
          icon: Icon(
            Icons.format_align_center,
            color: selectedIndex == 2 ? Colors.cyanAccent : Colors.white,
          ),
          onPressed: () {
            setState(() {
              gridNumber = 1;
              selectedIndex = 2;
            });
          },
        ),
        IconButton(
          icon: Icon(
            Icons.format_align_right,
            color: selectedIndex == 3 ? Colors.cyanAccent : Colors.white,
          ),
          onPressed: () {
            setState(() {
              gridNumber = 5;
              selectedIndex = 3;
            });
          },
        ),
     ],
```

Comment: wow I didn't realize writing them in seperate lines makes a different ._. cheers. excuse me for my silly question lol

Comment: You said its not the best approach, would you mind explaining why/what the best approach is? I would highly appreciate it for my learning

Comment: @Texv I said it's not a best approach, because 1) you are introducing magic numbers in code. In future someone (or even you) will be confused when you see selectedIndex and some 1, 2, 3 all around your code. 2) If you need more icons like that, you have to keep remember to update the selectedIndex property. If you forgot or mis-assign value then it will be hard to find. It's my thinking.

For me, the best approach would be to create own widget which can handle the same behaviour regardless number of buttons and without depending on hard-coded numbers.

Comment: thanks :) I think I understand your point but still not really sure how to implement the same behaviour without numbers in a widget. Did you mean like a tabbar widget with a controller and I call the function upon controller's index?

Comment: @Texv: Yes, you are correct. You have to create a widget something like a tabbar or radio button which has this kind of behaviour (when one is selected, others will get de-selected automatically). You can see one custom radio button widget implementation(This will give you an idea, how to create a custom widget which can handle the select, deselect automatically). https://stackoverflow.com/a/60738876/1104384